# Why is this property undefined for the function class but defined for an instance of the same?

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the following example taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

```
function doSomething(){}
doSomething.prototype.foo = "bar";
var doSomeInstancing = new doSomething();
doSomeInstancing.prop = "some value";
console.log("doSomeInstancing.prop:      " + doSomeInstancing.prop);
console.log("doSomeInstancing.foo:       " + doSomeInstancing.foo);
console.log("doSomething.prop:           " + doSomething.prop);
console.log("doSomething.foo:            " + doSomething.foo);
console.log("doSomething.prototype.prop: " + doSomething.prototype.prop);
console.log("doSomething.prototype.foo:  " + doSomething.prototype.foo);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
doSomeInstancing.prop:      some value
doSomeInstancing.foo:       bar
doSomething.prop:           undefined
doSomething.foo:            undefined
doSomething.prototype.prop: undefined
doSomething.prototype.foo:  bar
```

I don't get why doSomething.foo is undefined. foo was added to doSomething's prototype, shouldn't the interpreter find it there once it doesn't find it in the object's instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.prototype` property is a bit confusing. It doesn't refer to the internal prototype of the current object - rather, when a function has a `prototype` property, instances will have an internal prototype of the `.prototype` object on the function.

The function itself (here, `doSomething`) isn't anywhere on the prototype chain for `doSomeInstancing`. These are the prototype chains here:

```
<- here means: "has an internal prototype of"

doSomething <- Function.prototype <- Object.prototype
doSomeInstancing <- doSomething.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

```js
function doSomething(){}
const doSomeInstancing = new doSomething();

console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(doSomething) === Function.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(doSomeInstancing) === doSomething.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(doSomething.prototype) === Object.prototype
);
```

So when the interpreter tries to look up the `foo` property on `doSomething`, it doesn't exist on it nor on any of the objects on `doSomething`'s *internal* prototype chain, so `doSomething.foo` evaluates to `undefined`.

(The internal prototype of an object can be accessed with `__proto__` (deprecated) or `Object.getPrototypeOf`. This sounds similar to, but is *very different* from the `.prototype` property of a function, which is only the internal prototype of objects instantiated from that function.)

The `foo` property is only on the `.prototype` property of `doSomething`, but not on `doSomething` itself, nor on any of `doSomething`'s prototypal ancestor objects.

Comment: Not sure why most tutorials seem to gloss over this, it's very confusing unless it's spelled out this way. I'm still wrapping my head around the concept but your answer makes more sense than anything else I've found. Thanks!